# TypeError: cannot convert the series to <type 'float'>

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas

My code is and I have some difficulties to make it run correctly.

```
import scipy.special as sps
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import norm
from scipy.stats import gamma
from math import exp
########################################

### DADOS


dados= [2.3572833,0.7383197,14.1423990,2.0310423,7.1052727,1.8851099,12.9464459,4.4056236,1.0471756,0.4672236]

temp = pd.DataFrame(dados)

##########################################

def fx(x, t):
    prod = 1.0
    for i in range(0, len(x)):
        prod *= ((t[0]/t[1])* exp(- (x[i]/t[1]) ) * exp(-t[0] * exp(-(x[i]/t[1]) ) ) )
        return prod

#########################

def L(x, t):
    n = len(x)
    return fx(x,t)


##########################################

###  MCMC

def mcmc(N=[], k={"t1": 1, "t2": 1}, x=[]):
    chute = {"t1": [1], "t2": [1]}
    M = chute
    hiper = {"t1": [0.1, 0.1], "t2": [0.1, 0.1]} 
    contador = {"t1": [], "t2": []} 

    thetas = M.keys()
    for i in range(N - 1):
        for j in thetas:

            if j == "t1": 

                M[j].append( np.random.gamma(shape = M[j][-1], scale = k[j]) )
                lista = [ [ M[l][-1] for l in thetas] , [ M[l][-1] if l!=j else M[l][-2] for l in thetas ] ]
                t1 =  gamma.pdf(M[j][-1], a = hiper[j][0], scale = hiper[j][1]) * L(x, lista[0]) * gamma.pdf(M[j][-2], a = M[j][-1], scale = k[j])
                t2 =  gamma.pdf(M[j][-2], a = hiper[j][0], scale = hiper[j][1]) * L(x, lista[1]) * gamma.pdf(M[j][-1], a = M[j][-2], scale = k[j])          

                teste = (t1/t2)


            else:

                M[j].append( np.random.gamma(shape = M[j][-1], scale = k[j]) )
                lista = [ [ M[l][-1] for l in thetas] , [ M[l][-1] if l!=j else M[l][-2] for l in thetas ] ]
                t1 =  gamma.pdf(M[j][-1], a = hiper[j][0], scale = hiper[j][1]) * L(x, lista[0]) * gamma.pdf(M[j][-2], a = M[j][-1], scale = k[j])
                t2 =  gamma.pdf(M[j][-2], a = hiper[j][0], scale = hiper[j][1]) * L(x, lista[1]) * gamma.pdf(M[j][-1], a = M[j][-2], scale = k[j])          

                teste = (t1/t2)

        if (min(1, teste) < np.random.uniform(low=0, high=1)) or (np.isinf(teste)) or (np.isnan(teste)):
            M[j][-1] = M[j][-2]
            contador[j].append(0)
        else:
            contador[j].append(1)

    M = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(M)
    contador = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(contador)
    cont = contador.apply(sum)
    print(cont)

    return (M)

N = int(input("Entre com o N: "))

MP = mcmc(N=N, x=temp)

print(MP)
```

And it generates an error that I can not solve.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "teste2.py", line 92, in <module>
    MP = mcmc(N=N, x=temp)
  File "teste2.py", line 71, in mcmc
    t1 =  gamma.pdf(M[j][-1], a = hiper[j][0], scale = hiper[j][1]) * L(x, lista[0]) * gamma.pdf(M[j][-2], a = M[j][-1], scale = k[j])
  File "teste2.py", line 40, in L
    return fx(x,t)
  File "teste2.py", line 32, in fx
    prod *= ((t[0]/t[1])* exp(- (x[i]/t[1]) ) * exp(-t[0] * exp(-(x[i]/t[1]) ) ) )
  File "/home/karlla/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 78, in wrapper
    "{0}".format(str(converter)))
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <type 'float'>
```

I already tried to do several things that I found on the internet and it did not work. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Im not completely familiar w/ the syntax of 2.0, but are you sure you have to do 
`fx(x=dados,t=[1,1])` instead of just `fx(dados,[1,1])`

Comment: I put the complete code.

Comment: And now there is too much code to read. Learn about [mcve]

Comment: it seams it tries to do `float(pd.Series())` but `float()` can't do it. So error message shows you where in code is problem so use `print()` to see what values you have in variables - maybe you have something different than you expect.

Comment: BTW: code works for `N = 0` and `N = 1`

Comment: Why is this tagged as *both* Python 2.7 and 3.x?

Answer (score 1):

Use `print()` to test your data in function

```
def fx(x, t):
    prod = 1.0

    print('x:', type(x), x)
    print('t:', type(t), t)

    for i in range(0, len(x)):
        print('i:', i)
        print('x[i]:', type(x[i]), x[i])
        #print('x[0][i]:', type(x[0][i]), x[0][i])

        a = t[0]/t[1]
        print('a:', type(a), a)

        b = -(x[i]/t[1])
        print('b:', type(b), b)

        exp_b = exp(b)
        print('exp(b):', type(exp_b), exp_b)

        c = -t[0]
        print('c:', type(c), c)

        prod *= a * exp_b * exp(c * exp_b)
        print('prod:', type(prod), prod)

    print('exit fx')
    return prod
```

> I don't know what you try to do so maybe my result is wrong.

It shows problem with `pandas` because you have 2-dimensional `DataFrame` but you treat it as 1-dimensional `list`

---

`x` is `DataFrame`.

When you do `x[i]` you probably expect i-th element in column - in other word `element in row number "i"` but for pandas `x[i]` means `get column with number/name 'i'` so `x[0]` doesn't give you first element from column but full column (Series) which number/name in `"0"`.  (but at the same time `len(x)` gives you number of rows, not columns)

So `x[i]` is `Series` and you have

```
exp(Series)
```

and Python doesn't know how to convert `Series` to `float` and you get your error.

---

You need `x[0][i]` to get i-th element from column "0"`

```
def fx(x, t):
    prod = 1.0

    print('x:', type(x), x)
    print('t:', type(t), t)

    for i in range(len(x)):
        print('i:', i)
        print('x[0][i]:', type(x[0][i]), x[0][i])

        a = t[0]/t[1]
        print('a:', type(a), a)

        b = -(x[0][i]/t[1])
        print('b:', type(b), b)

        exp_b = exp(b)
        print('exp(b):', type(exp_b), exp_b)

        c = -t[0]
        print('c:', type(c), c)

        prod *= a * exp_b * exp(c * exp_b)
        print('prod:', type(prod), prod)

    print('exit fx')
    return prod
```

shorter

```
def fx(x, t):
    prod = 1.0
    for i in range(len(x)):
        a = t[0]/t[1]
        b = -(x[0][i]/t[1])
        exp_b = exp(b)
        c = -t[0]
        prod *= a * exp_b * exp(c * exp_b)
    return prod
```

and better - without `range(len())`

```
def fx(x, t):
    prod = 1.0

    a = t[0]/t[1]
    c = -t[0]

    for val in x[0]:
        b = -(val/t[1])
        exp_b = exp(b)
        prod *= a * exp_b * exp(c * exp_b)

    return prod
```

After that there is no problem with this function - but still there are other problems but I don't know what you try to do and can't help more.

Comment: `Series` objects can act like numpy arrays, so there's no need for loops.

Comment: @PaulH yes, `numpy` and `pandas` are powerfull but I don't know what OP tried to do in this function so I only tried to find problem and describe it.